# Solving nullspace of symbolic functions

Tags: julia, linear-algebra, symbolic-math

I have symbolic functions (For example `x^2`, `x+1`, etc) and try to find linear combinations that equal zero.

I wrote a Julia program using `Symbolic.jl`. In the documentation, it says that most Julia methods work with expressions, however, my program:

```
using Symbolics, LinearAlgebra
@variables n
p1 = :(n + 1)
p2 = :(n + 3)
p3 = :(n + 2)
A = [p1 p2 p3]
nullspace_A = nullspace(A)
println(nullspace_A)
```

Throws the error:

```
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching one(::Type{Expr})
```

I'm guessing that `nullspace` in `LinearAlgebra` does not support symbolic expressions. Is there a method that does? Is there maybe a module that is more suitable or a programming language? Efficiency is key and the real examples will contain more complex functions like factorials/gamma functions.

Comment: If you represent each expression in terms of some basis functions e.g. {1, x, x^2, ...} then you can solve for the nullspace numerically. But I'm not sure there's something that is general enough to recognize things like gamma(z+1) - z*gamma(z) = 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find a couple of solutions to my problem...

### Python - sympy

Python has the `sympy` module, that allows to solve symbolic equations for multiple variables. I managed to find nullspaces for `{(x - 1)!, x * (x - 2)!, (x - 2)!}` and even `{gamma(x - 1), gamma(x - 2), x * gamma(x - 2)}`. The code is straight forward:

```
>>>from sympy import solve, factorial
>>>from sympy.abc import a, b, c, x
>>>eq = a * factorial(x - 1) + b * x * factorial(x - 2) + c * factorial(x - 2)
>>>print(solve(eq, a, b, c, set=True))
([a, b, c], {((-b*x + b - c)/x, b, c)})
>>>eq = -b * x + b - c - a * x
>>>print(solve(eq, a, b, c, set=True))
([a, b], {(-c, c)})
```

However, as soon as things get more complicated, `sympy` fails. For example

`{upper_gamma(x, -1), upper_gamma(x - 1, -1), x * upper_gamma(x - 1, -1), (-1) ^ x}` or
`{(x - 1) * upper_gamma(x - 1, -1) + (-1) ^ (x - 1), upper_gamma(x - 1, -1), x * upper_gamma(x - 1, -1), (-1) ^ x}` or even
`{(x - 1) * y - z, y, x * y, z}` (Though, I have not ruled out user-error by 100%)

#### --------------Update--------------

Do not use `solve` for this problem, use `solve_undetermined_coeffs` instead. Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76216186/sympy-solve-fails-to-find-nullspace-of-easy-equation/76218144#76218144) for more context.

### Mathematica

Mathematica is the language used by wolfram-alpha. It is probably one of the most powerful CAS, however, it is not free to use

---

There are some other options, such as `Matlab`. I will update this answer if I find out more.