# Sympy solve fails to find nullspace of easy equation

Tags: python, sympy, linear-algebra, symbolic-math

I am trying to find the nullspace of various function-sets with pythons module `sympy`. It managed to find the solution to some sets like
`{(x - 1)!, x * (x - 2)!, (x - 2)!}`
My code is

```
from sympy import solve, factorial
from sympy.abc import a, b, c, x
eq = a * factorial(x - 1) + b * x * factorial(x - 2) + c * factorial(x - 2)
print(solve(eq, a, b, c, set=True))  #  output: ([a, b, c], {((-b*x + b - c)/x, b, c)})
eq = -b * x + b - c - a * x
print(solve(eq, a, b, c, set=True)) #  output: ([a, b], {(-c, c)})
```

However, it struggled with the set
`{upper_gamma(x, -1), upper_gamma(x - 1, -1), x * upper_gamma(x - 1, -1), (-1) ^ x}`
Which is fair enough, even wolfram-alpha cannot find the solution. However, I was surprised when it also failed on the simplified problem
`{(x - 1) * y - z, y, x * y, z}`
My code was again the same

```
eq = a * (x-1) * y - a * z + b * y + c * x * y + d * z
print(solve(eq, a, b, c, d, set=True))  # output: ([a, b, c, d], {((b*y + c*x*y + d*z)/(-x*y + y + z), b, c, d)})
```

I expected the solution `([a, b, c], {d, d, -d})`.
Am I using `solve` wrongly or is the equation to hard for this solver?

Comment: Some practical comments about formatting your question: you should remove the `>>>` part from the code, that makes it easier to copy for other people. Also, if you tag `python` as well as `sympy` then your code will be highlighted correctly. Finally a clarification question: what is the correct solution for the equation that you expect to get?

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that tags influence code-highlighting.

Comment: Most of the general programming language tags (like `python`, `java`, `c++` etc) have automatic highlighting. Some library tags have it as well, like `pandas`, but `sympy` doesn't have such an association. You can always add highlighting manually independent of the tags by adding the language name after the triple backticks that start the code block, or if four spaces are used (like you did in this post) then you can set the highlighting by adding a comment `<!-- language-all: lang-or-tag-here -->` at the top of the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are depending on an implicit behaviour of `solve` that given a single equation not in a list that is linear in all unknowns it will assume that you are looking for an undetermined coefficients solution which is semantically something quite different from an ordinary solution.

The difference between these can be seen like:

```
In [5]: solve(a*x + b*y, a, b, set=True)
Out[5]: ([a, b], {(0, 0)})

In [6]: solve([a*x + b*y], a, b, set=True)
Out[6]: 
⎛        ⎧⎛-b⋅y    ⎞⎫⎞
⎜[a, b], ⎨⎜─────, b⎟⎬⎟
⎝        ⎩⎝  x     ⎠⎭⎠
```

Here the first case is returning values of `a` and `b` that can make the expression identically zero for all possible values of `x` and `y`. The second case is treating `x` and `y` as being fixed but unspecified parameters and returning the set of possible values for `a` and `b` as functions of the symbolic parameters `x` and `y` that could make the expression zero.

Conceptually these are two very different things and it would be better if solve did not mix them up in a single end-user function. The difference that you see is because your equation is being treated like the second case rather than the first. That being said I cannot reproduce the output you report with the most recent version of SymPy (1.11.1):

```
In [1]: a, b, c, d = symbols('a, b, c, d')

In [2]: eq = a * (x-1) * y - a * z + b * y + c * x * y + d * z
   ...: print(solve(eq, a, b, c, d, set=True))  # output: ([a, b, c, d], {((b*y + c*x*y + d*z)/(-x*y + y 
   ...: + z), b, c, d)})
([a, b, c, d], {(d, d, -d, d)})
```

If I pass `eq` in a list then I do see it:

```
In [7]: solve([eq], a, b, c, d, set=True)
Out[7]: 
⎛              ⎧⎛      b⋅y          c⋅x⋅y          d⋅z             ⎞⎫⎞
⎜[a, b, c, d], ⎨⎜- ─────────── - ─────────── - ───────────, b, c, d⎟⎬⎟
⎝              ⎩⎝  x⋅y - y - z   x⋅y - y - z   x⋅y - y - z         ⎠⎭⎠
```

In any case it is best not to depend on using `solve` this way. I suggest to use `solve` only for its primary purpose which is case 2 above and for that it should always be called with a list (even for a single equation).

There is instead a function `solve_undetermined_coeffs` which is the explicit function for doing what you want to do here:

```
In [9]: solve_undetermined_coeffs(eq, [a, b, c, d], [x, y, z])
Out[9]: {a: d, b: d, c: -d}
```

https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html#sympy.solvers.solvers.solve_undetermined_coeffs

Comment: Wow, thanks so much. I have no idea why my solve-method is behaving differently. I, too, have version 1.11.1 and am not using square brackets. However, solve_undetermined_coeffs works